# How to solve $(\partial_x + i\partial_y)u - c(\partial_x+i\partial_y)au=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The following equation,
$$(\partial_x + i\partial_y)u - c(\partial_x+i\partial_y)au=0$$

($a=a(x,y)$ and $\partial_x=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$)

with solution,
$$u=\exp(ca)f(x+iy)$$

where $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary entire functions, a is some scalar function and $c$ is a scalar.

How can I derive the solution ?

Comment: This sort of looks like Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: You say $a$ is a scalar function--a function of what?  Does it depend on $x$ and/or $y$?

Comment: It depends both of them.

Comment: Do you know how to write down the partial derivatives?  After that, it's just _a lot_ of tedious algebra.  I'm guessing it simplifies to something you can solve, but I don't know if I want to go through plugging everything in.

Comment: What do you mean by saying how to write down the partial derivatives ?

Comment: Oh, you want to derive the solutions, never mind, I thought those were test functions and you were supposed to find $f$ and $g$.

Comment: You might want to specify, to avoid confusion, if you mean $[(\partial_x + i \partial_y)(au)]$ or $[(\partial_x + i \partial_y)a]u$. In other words does the derivative act on everything behind it or just the first term. I assume you mean the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Your equation can be written

$$\partial_x (\log u-ca) + i\partial_y(\log u - ca) = 0$$

This equation has the solution $\log u - ca = g$ for any $g$ that satisfy

$$\partial_x g + i\partial_yg = 0$$

Comment: While this is a neat observation, I think complex logarithms should be avoided at all costs, if only for the idiosyncrasies they cause. +1 though.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this via characteristics and a variant of integrating factors. (It took me a while to realize that your operator on the second term is the $\bar{\partial}$ derivative of $a$, not $au$.) Let's multiply our PDE by $\exp(-ca)$. Then our PDE becomes

$$0 = \exp(-ca)(\partial_x+i\partial_y)u-c\exp(-ca)(\partial_x+i\partial_y)a\cdot u \Longrightarrow 0 = (\partial_x+i\partial_y)(\exp(-ca)u).$$

Suppose $v = \exp(-ca)u$ is actually a function of another variable $t$: $v(x(t),y(t))$, then

$$\frac{d}{dt}v(x(t),y(t)) = \partial_x v\frac{dx}{dt}+\partial_y v\frac{dy}{dt}.$$

If we set $\frac{dx}{dt} = 1$ and $\frac{dy}{dt} = i$, we get that

$$\frac{d}{dt}v = 0$$

by our above PDE. For this solution set, $x = t+C$ and $y = it+D$. Further our above ODE says that $v$ is constant on our characteristic curve. There is some freedom in how we parameterize our characteristic curves (as seen by our constants $C$ and $D$) but if we reparameterize, we can in fact just take $x = t$ and $y= it+D$.

Since $\frac{dv}{dt} = 0$, we just need to determine its value at $0$ and we will have a general solution for $v$. Let $v(0) = f(y_0)$ (since $x_0 = x(0) = 0$). But then $y_0 = y(0) = D$. We also have that $ix=it$ and so we can solve for $D$: $D = y-ix$. Thus

$$v(t) = v(x(t),y(t)) = f(D) = f(y-ix) = f(-i(x+iy)) = g(x+iy),$$

where $g$ is some entire function (since $v$ solves $\bar{\partial} v = 0$). Now just assemble the pieces.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\pars{\partial_{x} + \ic\partial_{y}}{\rm u}\pars{x,y}
     -c\pars{\partial_{x} + \ic\partial_{y}}{\rm a}\pars{x,y}{\rm u}\pars{x,y}
     = 0:\ {\large ?}}$

1. > Your notation is confused. For the second term, I'll assume $\ds{\pars{\partial_{x} + \ic\partial_{y}}}$ is 'applied' just to $\ds{\rm a}$. It means I understand $\quad\ds{\pars{\partial_{x} + \ic\partial_{y}}{\rm au}}\quad$
   > as $\ds{\bracks{\pars{\partial_{x} + \ic\partial_{y}}{\rm a}}{\rm u}}$
   >
   > In that case, we can rewrite the equation as:
   > $$
   > \fermi\pars{x,y}{\rm u}\pars{x,y}=0\,,\qquad\qquad
   > \fermi\pars{x,y} \equiv
   > \bracks{1 - \pars{\partial_{x} + \ic\partial_{y}}{\rm a}\pars{x,y}}
   > $$
   > The solution will be $\ds{{\rm u}\pars{x,y} = 0}$ unless $\ds{\fermi\pars{x,y} = 0}$.
2. Otherwise, 
   \begin{align}
   0&=\pars{\partial_{x} + \ic\partial_{y}}{\rm u}\pars{x,y}
   -\bracks{c\pars{\partial_{x} + \ic\partial_{y}}{\rm a}\pars{x,y}}{\rm u}\pars{x,y}
   \\[3mm]&-c\,{\rm a}\pars{x,y}\pars{\partial_{x} + \ic\partial_{y}}{\rm u}\pars{x,y}
   \end{align}
   The equation becomes:
   \begin{align}
   &\bracks{\partial_{x} + \ic\partial_{y}
   +\phi\pars{x,y}}{\rm u}\pars{x,y} = 0
   \\[3mm]&\mbox{where}\quad\phi\pars{x,y} \equiv
   {c\pars{\partial_{x} + \ic\partial_{y}}{\rm a}\pars{x,y} \over c\,{\rm a}\pars{x,y} - 1}
   \end{align}